# Informatica Variable Scope in Worklet

Tags: variables, informatica

There are n number of worklets and each worklet contains 2 sessions.

In the first session, there is a variable assignment as below.

> SETVARIABLE($$FILE, FileName)

In the second session, the variable **$$FILE** is used in the preSQL Query.

There are many worklets like this in a given workflow.

Question here is, If multiple worklets run in parallel, Will it impact (Overlap the value from other worklets) the value of variable **$$FILE** in each worklet.

If the question is not clear. Please do comment.

Thanks,
Shibin

Comment: Is the variable declared on the workflow or on the worklet?

Comment: Have a look at this [post](https://mahaveersingh.wordpress.com/2012/01/14/informatica-parameters-and-their-scopes/) which gives a brief overview of variable scope in Informatica. As per this you can configure it so that each worklet has it's own unique value for a variable/parameter.